# The UK has voted to leave the EU. I am a British citizen living in Canada who is looking for employment within the EU, how will this affect me?

Tags: job-search, united-kingdom, europe

I recently graduated from a Canadian university, and am now looking at jobs within the EU; I love travelling and experiencing new cultures, hence why I would prefer to move elsewhere for this next chapter in my life. I've been living in Canada for 9 years, but previously I was living in England (I am a dual citizen).

I've now started the process of looking for engineering jobs in countries within the EU. From my understanding, before the EU referendum my citizenship would allow me to find employment in these countries without needing a visa.

I am wondering at how the process will now work, given current circumstances, for British citizens living abroad who want to find work within the EU. Thanks in advance.

Comment: At this stage, I don't think anybody has a clue.  It will become a point for lawyers to discuss over the next couple of years.  Until then, the answer is "nobody knows".

Comment: Jane S is correct. No one knows at this point, it could go either way depending on the governments decision. I wouldn't worry too much though, this won't be for at least 2 years and should not dissuade you from looking at other opportunities overseas.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, everything makes sense. Although I'm wondering why I was downvoted... Not specific enough?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm guessing it was because it's going to be a purely speculative answer at this point.  The international lawyers are going to have a field day before there is any clarity on this point, not to mention there is no real idea as to what could happen during that time.  It's not a question that fits in the Q&A format, because right now there _is_ no answer.

Comment: @JaneS I see. Makes sense, should I delete the question or leave it open for an answer in the future

Comment: I'd suggest deleting it.  Even later it will be more of a question over at law.SE.

Comment: Ask in expatriates.stackexchange.com, since this is a problem for people living in different countries, not a problem in the workplace.

Comment: Don't forget, they might ultimately not go with it. 
The public did vote, but there's always a slight chance, that the government could in the end disregard the vote's outcome. Don't worry so much about it right now. Cross that bridge when you get to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am wondering at how the process will now work, given current circumstances

Since you ask about current circumstances, rather than the unknowable future, the answer is easy: The UK ***is*** a member of the EU and enjoys all treaty rights and obligations that that membership brings. In particular, UK citizens ***have*** the unconditional right to live and work in any EU member state.

I do not however have any data on how the recent referendum vote has affected EU-non-UK employers' willingness to recruit UK citizens; but I suspect good-quality data on that subject will be hard to find.

*note that I have written this answer in the present tense since I relate the facts at the time of writing. In the future this answer may well need to be edited, of course*

Comment: The right of freedom of movement is not unconditional, but it can only be circumscribed for very limited reasons.

Answer (score 4):

From anecdotal evidence I've heard, companies are not avoiding engineering hire on the basis of Brexit situation. There are several reasons:

- A situation where highly skilled engineering hire must be sent home seems incredibly unlikely
- By the time something happens, the cost would have been recouped (engineering hire esp. with less experience typically don't stick around for a long time anyway)
- It's still really, really hard to get great engineers/scientists. The tiny risk of potentially losing them due to visa issues isn't worth hedging against when compared to the much bigger risk of not having great talent

This is based only on a tiny, tiny sample size though.